# When i click edit icon it does not open input box?

Tags: angular, typescript

When i click edit button it does not open my input box. After Clicking my edit option when i click another input box it will changed to input box.
I need to change input box when i click edit option.

```
                    <form class="form-add-expenses" (submit)="addItem($event)">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="masterItem.itemName" placeholder="Item Name" name="name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="masterItem.itemType" placeholder="Item Type" name="type">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="masterItem.itemDescription" placeholder="Item Description" name="description">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="masterItem.itemCurrentPrice" placeholder="Item Price" name="price">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-1">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md">add</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <table class="table-responsive table-bordered table-striped">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
                        <td><!-- {{ item.itemName }} -->
                            <span *ngIf="i !== indexes">{{ item.itemName }}</span>
                            <span *ngIf="i === indexes"><input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="editUpdate.itemName" name="update.name" (keyup.enter)="UpdateItem()" (keyup.escape)="cancelEditingTodo()"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td><!-- {{ item.itemType }} -->
                            <span *ngIf="i !== indexes">{{ item.itemType }}</span>
                            <span *ngIf="i === indexes"><input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="editUpdate.itemType" name="update.type" (keyup.enter)="UpdateItem()" (keyup.escape)="cancelEditingTodo()"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td><!-- {{ item.itemDescription }} -->
                            <span *ngIf="i !== indexes">{{ item.itemDescription }}</span>
                            <span *ngIf="i === indexes"><input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="editUpdate.itemDescription" name="update.description" (keyup.enter)="UpdateItem()" (keyup.escape)="cancelEditingTodo()"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td><!-- {{ item.itemCurrentPrice }} -->
                            <span *ngIf="i !== indexes">{{ item.itemCurrentPrice }}</span>
                            <span *ngIf="i === indexes"><input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="editUpdate.itemCurrentPrice" name="update.price" (keyup.enter)="UpdateItem()" (keyup.escape)="cancelEditingTodo()"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span *ngIf="i !== indexes"><i class="fa fa-pencil" (click)="editItem(i)" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <span *ngIf="i === indexes"><button (click)="UpdateItem()" class="btn btn-md">Update</button></span>
                        </td>
                        <td><i class="fa fa-trash" (click)="deleteItem(i)" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

My typescript file is,

```
editItem(i: number) {
    this.indexes = i;
    this.editUpdate = this.items[this.indexes];
    console.log("edit",this.editUpdate);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

[ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html#!#detectChanges-anchor)

To reflect the changes , it will work like `$scope.$digest()` And will update( manually trigger) the changes, and it will start reflecting in your view. Because some time it happens that the digest cycle is not triggered to update the changes.

Hope it will help